# Issue in numpy 2D @ 1D matmul result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to rotate some coordinates in numpy using a 2x2 matrix `P` and the coordinates `internal` (stored as an `np.array` in a row). However, I get weird behavior when calculating `P @ internal`. The code below reproduces the behavior:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 0], dtype=np.float)
>>> c, s = np.cos(np.pi), np.sin(np.pi)
>>> p = np.matrix([[c, s], [-s, c]])
>>> b = p @ a
>>> b
matrix([[-1.0000000e+00, -1.2246468e-16]])
>>> b.shape
(1, 2)
>>> b[0].shape
(1, 2)
>>> b[0][0].shape
(1, 2)
>>> b[0][0][0].shape
(1, 2)
```

As can be seen, I cannot index into the matrix, and I suddenly have an extra dimension in what should be a 1D array. In [the documentation for numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) it states "If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the appended 1 is removed." However, I am failing to see this behavior, instead just seeing the weird nested shape.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Does this happen if you use `np.array` for `p` as well? It might just be an artifact of the deprecated `matrix` class.

Comment: @MadPhysicist This is exactly the issue. I have missed the deprecation warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, `b` is a [`matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). This is a deprecated subclass of [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), which is *always 2D*. Initializing a matrix with an `(N,)`-element vector appends 1 to the shape, turning it into an `(N, 1)` column, as expected. `b[0]` is also a matrix, but this time it is a row. The first row of the row is also a row, so the shape will stay the same no matter how many times you access the first row.

That being said, you can access individual matrix elements be using a row-column index:

```
>>> b[0, 0]
-1.0
```

**TL;DR**

Don't use `matrix`: it's deprecated and has issues/lack of support. Do `p = np.array([[c, s], [-s, c]])` instead, and you will see the expected behavior.